# Adding tuples in lists in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have lists of tuples and I cut each of the lists into two parts at the point when tuples = (x, y=-1)

This is the code:

```
testList = [
[(0.0, -1.0), (0.5, -0.002), (2.0, -0.1613676), (2.5, 1.08492417852)],
[(0.0, -0.99604032), (0.5, -1.0), (2.0, -0.1613832766676), (2.5, 1.0849852)],
[(4.5, 0.154484), (5.0, -1.0), (5.5, -0.34), (6.0, -0.44)],
[(88.5, 3127.7763767), (89.0, 13.449714), (90.0, -1.0)]]

def c_slice(lst):
    for slst in lst:
        start = 0
        for idx,(_,y) in enumerate(slst):
            if y == -1:
               yield [slst[start:idx+1], slst[idx:]]
               break

out = list(c_slice(testList))

print(out[0])
# [[(0.0, -1.0)], [(0.0, -1.0), (0.5, -0.002), (2.0, -0.1613676), (2.5, 1.08492417852)]]
print(out[1])
# [[(0.0, -0.99604032), (0.5, -1.0)], [(0.5, -1.0), (2.0, -0.1613832766676), (2.5, 1.0849852)]]
print(out[2])
# [[(4.5, 0.154484), (5.0, -1.0)], [(5.0, -1.0), (5.5, -0.34), (6.0, -0.44)]]
print(out[3])
# [[(88.5, 3127.7763767), (89.0, 13.449714), (90.0, -1.0)], [(90.0, -1.0)]]
```

**How could I set some limits to my result?** For example,

1. If the first list in the result doesn't have (x, y>0), add (0, 0) into the beginning of the list. (Like out[0][0] and out[1][0]).
2. If the second list in the result doesn't have (x, y>0), add (90, 0) into the end of the list. (Like out[2][1] and out[3][1])

p.s. The position to add tuples is based on the x coordinate. For example, (0, 0) has the smallest x, so it is always added at the beginning of the list. In contrast, (90, 0) has the biggest x coordinate, so it is always added at the last of the list.

I am trying to get this:

```
print(out[0])
# [[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -1.0)], [(0.0, -1.0), (0.5, -0.002), (2.0, -0.1613676), (2.5, 1.08492417852)]]
print(out[1])
# [[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -0.99604032), (0.5, -1.0)], [(0.5, -1.0), (2.0, -0.1613832766676), (2.5, 1.0849852)]]
print(out[2])
# [[(4.5, 0.154484), (5.0, -1.0)], [(5.0, -1.0), (5.5, -0.34), (6.0, -0.44), (90.0, 0.0)]]
print(out[3])
# [[(88.5, 3127.7763767), (89.0, 13.449714), (90.0, -1.0)], [(90.0, -1.0), (90.0, 0.0)]]
```

Comment: Can you explain deep what kind work you should do? Are there some rules to do this `[(0.0, 0.0), (0.0, -1.0)]` or to that `[(90.0, -1.0), (90.0, 0.0)]`?  Is your goals based on index of inner list or on index of the outer list? In the first two cases you prepend the tuple, but in the second ones you appen, why?

Comment: You don't add a tuple in cases like `(5.0, -1.0)`, why?

Comment: @SorcererApprentice Hi, I edited my question, please take a look.

Comment: we add at beginning if `x <= x/2` and at end, don't we?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try it like this

```
testList = [
    [(0.0, -1.0), (0.5, -0.002), (2.0, -0.1613676), (2.5, 1.08492417852)],
    [(0.0, -0.99604032), (0.5, -1.0), (2.0, -0.1613832766676), (2.5, 1.0849852)],
    [(4.5, 0.154484), (5.0, -1.0), (5.5, -0.34), (6.0, -0.44)],
    [(88.5, 3127.7763767), (89.0, 13.449714), (90.0, -1.0)]
]


def c_slice(rows):
    for row in rows:
        for idx, (_, y) in enumerate(row):
            if y == -1:
                start = row[:idx + 1]
                end = row[idx:]
                start = [(0, 0)] + start if all([y < 0 for _, y in start]) else start
                end = end + [(90, 0)] if all([y < 0 for _, y in end]) else end
                yield [start, end]
                break


out = list(c_slice(testList))

for i in out:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

I coded this solution:

```
testList = [
[(0.0, -1.0), (0.5, -0.002), (2.0, -0.1613676), (2.5, 1.08492417852)],
[(0.0, -0.99604032), (0.5, -1.0), (2.0, -0.1613832766676), (2.5, 1.0849852)],
[(4.5, 0.154484), (5.0, -1.0), (5.5, -0.34), (6.0, -0.44)],
[(88.5, 3127.7763767), (89.0, 13.449714), (90.0, -1.0)]]

def c_slice(lst):
    for slst in lst:
        start = 0
        for idx,(x,y) in enumerate(slst):
            if y == -1:
                if x <= len(slst)/2:
                    yield [[(x, 0)] + slst[start:idx+1], slst[idx:]]
                else:
                    yield [slst[start:idx+1] + [(x, 0)], slst[idx:]]
                break

out = list(c_slice(testList))

print(out[0])
print(out[1])
print(out[2])
print(out[3])
```